# Interpolating in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, interpolation, error-999999

I am trying to make a raster from point data. My data is in .txt form and contains of x,y,z; that is, coordinates and elevation. I have about 156000 points. So, these points are imported into ArcMap, showing up at the correct positions.

Now, for some reason I can't make these into a raster. Whatever tool I try (spatial analyst, 3D analyst...) nothing works! I just get an error 99999 code.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Have you started from the [**Fundamentals of Surfaces**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q80000005z000000) page?  If so, can you list the precise steps that you have performed and highlight where what you expected to see started to depart from what you observed?  Please do this via an edit to your question.

Comment: Are the (x,y) coordinates *already* points on a regular grid or not?  You have different options when they are, options that you should favor trying first.

Answer (score 1):

The points you're trying to interpolate from must be a feature layer.

...At least for the interpolation tools I'm familiar with (IDW, Kriging, etc). I'm assuming you plotted x/y data from the txt file. Export that data to a shp file or feature class and you shouldn't have any issues.

Also, you can get more specific error information to help you diagnose the problem by going to  the Geoproccessing drop-down and clicking on "Results."